# How to typeset a chord with variable note length in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I am typesetting a score using Lilypond but I am struggling with the following bar:

[image: bar]

I tried `<fa la> <<fa4 {la8 sib}>> …` but it does not render properly.

**Global settings.**

```
\version "2.20.0"
\language "italiano"
```

**Staff settings.**

```
\key fa\major
\clef bass
```

Comment: Since this wasn't called out specifically, you don't have "chords"; you have multiple independent voices, which Lilypond treats differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Glorfindel's answer is correct, it's a bit long-winded. Depending on your needs and the rest of the score, you can get the exact same results by simply inputting

```
<<
    {
      la4 la8 sib
    }
    \\
    {
      fa4 fa
    }
>>
```

In other words, you can do this without all of the `\new Voice = "this"` and `\voiceThat` commands.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you could use some [single staff polyphony](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices#single_002dstaff-polyphony).

The following should work; it sets up two voices, one with stems up, the other with stems down, so they can play/sing different rhythms.

```
\score {
    \new Staff <<
        \key fa\major
        \clef bass
        \new Voice = "first" { \voiceOne la4 la8 sib }
        \new Voice = "second" { \voiceTwo fa4 fa }
    >>
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Modifying @Richard's answer.
Putting `\relative do` at the start of each voice keeps the voice in the same octave (in the second voice).
Using `q` to repeat chords is very useful.

```
<<
   \relative do' {
    la4 la8 sib do4 do8 sib |
   }
   \\
   \relative do {
    fa4 fa <fa la> q |
   }
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a little bit confusing to me so I'll post a full working example (kudos to @elements in space for the hint) as I had issues understanding basic sheet concepts

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "espanol"
\score {
    \new PianoStaff <<
      \new Staff = "first" \relative {
        \key re \major
        re''8[mi]
        la[sol]
        fas4
      }
      \new Staff = "second" \relative {
        \key re \major
        \clef bass
        <la dos>4
        << { dos } \\ {la8[mi]} >>
        <fas dos>4
      }
    >>
}
```

[image]